# Magento: How to retrieve the minimal price of (i.e.) grouped products?

Tags: magento

I am trying to display a grouped product's price on the product view page in Magento 1.7.0.2, just as it is being displayed in the category product listing ("Starting at: xx.xx"). I thought I could just use

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

to do so because it works the same way in the category product listing, but as everything I tried to do in Magento, it is not that easy because that method doesnt return anything on the product view page.

I looked a little deeper into Magento's code and figured out that the cause of this problem is the product's minimal price data not being set on the product view page ($_product->getMinimalPrice() returns null).

Therefore I did some research on how to load a product's minimal price which brought up ideas like

```
$_product->getPriceModel()->getMinimalPrice($_product);
```

which doesnt work because apparently that method was deprecated and removed in one of the last updates or

```
$priceModel = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogindex/price');
$priceModel->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$priceModel->setCustomerGroupId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId());

$minimalPrices = $priceModel->getMinimalPrices(array($_product->getId()));
$minimalPrice = $minimalPrices[0];
$_product->setData('minimal_price', $minimalPrice['value']);
$_product->setData('minimal_tax_class_id', $minimalPrice['tax_class_id']);
```

which doesnt work either because the table 'catalogindex_minimal_price' is empty.

So my question is, how does Magento load the minimal price in the category product listing?

Comment: I did some more research. When viewing the product listing, the product collection is loaded in Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer which adds the minimal price and other stuff to it by adding joins to the collection's SQL, but I have not yet found a model that does the same thing for single products. Because I don't really want to use a direct SQL query, I checked out the CatalogIndex module, but that module seems not to be working at all because all its indexing tables are empty. That module is either deprecated or I'm just too stupid to enable it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I looked a little deeper into Magento's code and tracked down how Magento loads the products of the product list. 
When viewing the product list, the product collection is loaded by the model Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer, which adds the minimal price and other stuff to the products in the collection by adding joins to the collection’s SQL, but I have not yet found a model that does the same thing for single products instead of collections.

Because I don’t want to use a direct SQL query, I checked out the CatalogIndex module, but that module seems not to be working at all because all its indexing tables are empty or even corrupted.

```
$data_grouped = Mage::getModel("catalogindex/data_grouped");
$minimal = $data_grouped->getMinimalPrice(array($_product->getId()), Mage::app()->getStore());
```

looked good at first but it gives me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_index_price.value' in 'field list'
```

The CatalogIndex module is either deprecated or I’m just too stupid to enable it.

However, I have now created a workaround in my price.phtml template, which uses the same method to retrieve the minimal price and tax percents as the product list does:
At the beginning of the template I added the following:

```
$this->setProduct(
    Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes())
        ->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", $this->getProduct()->getId())
        ->setPage(1, 1)
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->load()
        ->getFirstItem()
);
```

which may not be the perfect solution, but it does the job and it does it a little cleaner than iterating over all child products and finding the minimal price that way.

Comment: This worked for me. I was running this in a more standalone script, and I had to manually set the store using `setCurrentStore` or `setStoreId`. If you don't set it, it defaults to admin store, which doesn't have pricing information. Magento's query does an inner join instead of an outer join from products to the pricing table, so `addMinimalPrice` mysteriously caused the query to result in zero products.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer as much as a big HTML comment on Subsurf's answer. If you're reading this, you might be implementing your own custom module to display a product list. In my case, it's a single page just for wholesalers. My goal was to get a list of my own company's products and give them a list like it was another category. I copied my template's `list.phtml` to my new `content.phtml`. But `getMinimalPrice()` was returning `NULL`, meaning that when this code calls the `getPriceHtml()`, `price.phtml` wasn't showing wholesale pricing.

I did a simple module with index controller and a content.phtml. Using the boilerplate I see all over the net, in the `indexController.php` file, change:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
    'b2b',
    array('template' => 'b2b/content.phtml')
);
```

to:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List',
    'b2b',
    array('template' => 'b2b/content.phtml')
);
```

This does a lot of the heavy lifting for you to show the products list correctly.

---

Now, on to the template file, in my case `content.phtml`, you get your product collection and then use Subsurf's code in the top of the `foreach()` which repeats.

```
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
//          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
// doesn't work     ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value
        ->addFieldToFilter( array(
                array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>'143')
                , array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>'139')
            ))
        ;

echo "<p>There are ".count($_productCollection)." products: </p>";
echo '<div class="category-products">';
// List mode 
if($this->getMode()!='grid') { 
    $_iterator = 0;
    echo'<ol class="products-list" id="products-list">';
    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
        ?>          <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
        <?php 
        $_product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes())
            ->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", $_product->getId())
            ->setPage(1, 1)
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->load()
            ->getFirstItem()
            );
        echo "Minimal price: ".$_product->getMinimalPrice()."<br>\n";
```

Since this isn't a single product's page and I'm using other template code, `$this->setProduct()` didn't do anything for me. I guessed if there was a set, there might be a get, so `$_product=$this->getProduct()` was the magic my template's `price.phtml` needed to work properly. Then I noticed I could just assign the `Mage::` in `setProduct()` directly to `$_product`.

Thanks, Subsurf!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that will still allow you to use `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);` in your template, which then handles all the complex price display rules and puts "Starting at" before grouped product prices.

I'm using this for a custom featured product block. In a block class I have this function:

```
class MyCompany_Catalog_Block_Product_Featured extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {
  public function setGroupedProductPrice($group_product) {
   $prices = array();
   foreach ($group_product->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($group_product->getId()) as $ids) {
     foreach ($ids as $id) {
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
       $prices[] = $product->getPriceModel()->getPrice($product);
     }
   }
   ksort($prices);
   $group_product->setPrice(array_pop($prices));
  }
}
```

Then in the template:

```
<?php 
  if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped')
    $this->prepareGroupedProduct($_product);
  echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick without using a product collection:

```
$priceResource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogindex/price');

$select = $priceResource->getReadConnection()->select();
$select->from(
    array('price_table' => $priceResource->getMainTable())
)
    ->where('price_table.entity_id = ?', $_product->getId())
    ->where('price_table.website_id = ?', Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
    ->where('price_table.customer_group_id = ?', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId());

$result = $priceResource->getReadConnection()->fetchRow($select);
```

This code is adapted from `\Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Resource_Price::getMinimalPrices` and made suitable for one single product.